# Javascript - create an array of words and tags from a paragraph

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, split

I have this:

```
<p><strong>test the strong tag</strong> some dummy text <a href="#" target="_blank">test the link</a> some other text <a href="#" target="_blank">Test another link</a></p>
```

I need an JS array:

```
['<strong>Test the strong tag</strong>', 'some', 'dummy', 'text', '<a href="#" target="_blank">test the link</a>', 'some', 'other', 'text', '<a href="#" target="_blank">Test another link</a>']
```

Help, im giving up!

p.s. It's a part of a bigger idea to distribute the content of a section into horizontal slides (which can be animated to left and right). For that i need every word being wrapped into span to measure its position and determine if it belongs to the next "line". sry it's hard to explain the whole thing.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: this is not easy, but I'm trying to understand the use case of that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really neat problem and it was really fun to work on!
The solution: Assuming you named your p element test. Like this:

```
<p id="test"><strong>test the strong tag</strong> some dummy text <a href="#" target="_blank">test the link</a> some other text <a href="#" target="_blank">Test another link</a></p>
```

The javascript would be:

```
var nodes = document.getElementById("test").childNodes;
var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    if (nodes[i].nodeName == "#text") {
        arr.push(nodes[i].nodeValue);
        continue;
    }
    arr.push(nodes[i].outerHTML);
}
```

This works using the node part of HTML. HTML nodes include text and HTML elements. The first line just gets the nodes of an element called 'test'. The second line initializes an array to push to later. The third line starts iterating over the child nodes. The fourth through seventh lines deal with text nodes and the eighth line adds it to the array. If you want the text to be split like how you put in the question this code does it:

```
var nodes = document.getElementById("t").childNodes;
var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    if (nodes[i].nodeName == "#text") {
        arr = arr.concat(nodes[i].nodeValue.split(" "));
        continue;
    }
    arr.push(nodes[i].outerHTML);
}
arr.filter(v=>v!='');
```

Comment: Great! this is exactly what i needed! Thx for pointing out the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

So you want to have every tags on its own line, and every word not included in a tag being on its own line. 
I don't think there is a ready-made utility for that.

What I would do is writing a custom parser. You loop on every char and you execute these two primary checks :

- When you come across a **<** char, you switch the "tag" flag on. Then you read the tag name until **>** char. Keep the tag name in a variable. You keep adding chars until you find the corresponding closing tag, and you switch the "tag" flag off.
- When "tag" flag is off, you are in "word-mode", so you keep adding chars until you come across a space char.